# Are deleted questions actually salvageable?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, post-ban

I'm currently under a five-day question ban. It hinders my learning progress. I have so much more questions to ask! As I understand, it's because some of my questions were downvoted, though I'm not sure why. One of them was closed and [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74864834/when-are-non-void-methods-preferable-to-void-methods). I believe I improved it, but the chances of it being undeleted and reopened seem slim at best. Not once did I see any deleted question "brought back to life" like that. Does it mean I can't do anything with downvoted questions once they are deleted (in practice, not theoretically)?

[image]

Comment: As for your question about deleted questions, you're correct in that it is rare that they are undeleted. There is no review queue for them, and unless someone with 10k+ reputation finds your (deleted) post and votes to undelete, and then 2 more agree with that vote (likely finding it in the [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools)) then it'll stay deleted. This is why ensuring that you write a *good* question early on is important, and why editing it to improve if it is closed is too; you have 8 days to improve that question before it was deleted by the Community user.

Comment: You are currently question banned (not edit banned) and you were/are automatically rate limited for 3 days (ending on Jan. 5 so maybe that's where the 5 came from?). This is your only deleted question, though you have several other undeleted questions with score <= 0 which are contributing to the rate limit.

Comment: You might want to explicitly ask for advice on one of your questions here on meta. This allows to get in-depth feedback and draws enough attention to get a question undeleted  - if it was improved enough.

Comment: @HenryEcker "it's been three days, wait two more" so five in total

Comment: You are rate limited. You just need to post less often. Work on your next question in the meantime and make sure that it's the best you can do. Do some research. Ask colleagues to check grammar spelling and overall state of your question. Then when you are ready, post it in a couple of days.

Comment: Not being able to ask questions does not hinder your learning ability because that's not what asking questions is for.

Comment: @Dharman getting answers is the literal purpose of asking questions, isn't it? Googling can help only so much (believe me I do google)

Comment: @Dharman I don't have any "colleagues"

Comment: "I have so much more questions to ask!" -- if by "ask" you mean "post", then that's likely a significant part of the problem. I'd say writing a good question for SO is far harder than writing a good answer. (By good I mean well-researched, non-duplicate, and useful to a wider audience than just yourself)

Comment: @Dharman less often than what, several per week? I have, like, ten new questions daily. You must have been there as a beginner. I do research, but it often doesn't resolve your problem, especially if you don't yet know the coding terminology like the back of your hand ("Optional? What on earth is Optional? Codecademy never taught me that" and the like – but, I want to point out, it's not among the questions I would ask on SO, understanding the high standards adopted here)

Comment: The fact that you want/"need" to post a lot of questions is a likely indicator that [so] isn't the right place for you to be right now. More likely you need to be doing some (un)structured learning first, and then when you get truly stuck in that, you should be asking. [so] isn't a replacement for a teacher/online learning tool, nor a consultant.

Comment: @Larnu I came here only after I finished Learn Java. I also completed most of Learn Intermediate Java by this point

Comment: "I have so much more questions to ask!" - yes but you need to put them into Google or your favourite equivalent, not into the post question text box. Then you have a chance of finding *existing* answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Gimby I do google. Not always does it resolve an issue

Comment: You should post a new question here if you think that nobody else has ever asked it before and you think a potential answer will be helpful to other developers

Comment: The whole purpose of Stack Overflow is so that people don't have to ask so many new questions. Most common topics should already be covered here.

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev a few problems I noticed from your questions, 1) You don't seem to be searching enough or searching properly, one of your questions you had an error "int cannot be dereferenced" and if you used that in your search you would have found your answer. 2) You aren't creating [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the same question I refer to above you could have drastically shortened the example code you shared.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and the other posts in [faq]. Google never resolves an issue. At best it gives you a couple of leads to narrow down your search scope, investigate topics further. If Google returns null do not take that as a signal to ask a question on SO. Instead take that as a signal that you're searching for the wrong words / terms.

Comment: @Dharman. Re *"...check grammar spelling"*: Not in this case. The writing is extremely good (at least in relative terms).

Comment: Learning has been more easier than ever, I guess that's just expose a lot of people that's not good at learning...

Comment: @Alvi15 as long as you have funds. Otherwise, it's a slow and inefficient process (believe me, I tried it) – unless, that is, you have access to free and relevant feedback from real people with expertise. I hoped SO could provide the latter

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts in this question - "are questions salvageable" and "how to get a question undeleted".

Easy part first - to undelete question enough people need to vote to undelete it depending who/what deleted the question:

- the author deleted the question themselves - the author can undelete with a single vote
- community (Roomba auto-deletion) or other users deleted the question - 3 20K+ users can vote to undelete (but somehow one need to notify such users - there is no built in way to do so unlike for example re-opening which has a dedicated queue). 3 votes from non-moderators (potentially including author's vote) or 1 moderator vote.
- a moderator - only one of moderators (not necessarily the same one) can undelete the question with a single vote.

So, for practical purposes there are only two ways to un-delete a question - revert your own "delete" action or flag for moderator attention with a good explanation why it should be un-deleted. Posting on meta is another way to get more attention and possibly get the question un-deleted... but one better be 110% sure there is no way to improve the question as [meta-effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) is a thing.

Now to the harder part - are deleted questions salvageable in general. The answer is - not every question can be modified (in a way that is compatible with SO guidelines that prohibit replacing a question with totally different one) to become on-topic good quality question. For example, obviously off-topic non-programming questions like "how to cook pasta" or "what color is the White House" just can't be made into programming questions.

Note that not every programming-related question can be made on-topic either, some examples:

- searching for programming tools/libraries can't be asked as such. Showing research on what you already looked at is not enough even if it will likely make the post no longer be a downvote magnet. Some of such questions can be re-worded into "how-to" ("find library to gzip" can be asked as "how to gzip, I only see RLE in the standard library"), but there are plenty of "find a ..." that will always be "search for tools or other off-site resources".
- asking for an unbounded list of things ("what are new methods in v5.23 of ...") and unrestricted comparison of things ("list of all differences C# vs. Java") are unlikely to be editable into on-topic narrow enough questions.
- asking for architecture recommendations for large scale projects are unlikely to be editable to be narrow enough. Similar recommendations for a smaller scale problem ("what protocol to use to call my service") can be edited to allow for a concrete verifiable answer.
- most true opinion-based questions can't be edited to be on-topic. There are rare cases where one of opinions is clearly and unanimously bad ("should I use parametrized query or build SQL with string concatenation of user input"), but those are rare and pretty much guaranteed to be duplicates - while being a duplicate is not a reason to delete the question, requesting to un-delete a duplicate would require a lot of convincing.

There are also a lot of questions that can be edited in shape by adding [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I expect most of them not to be a good candidate for un-deletion either - when real MRE is created problem often is too obvious. For cases when author got "missing MRE" close votes/comments it may be good idea to at least try to create MRE and see if they still have the question - un-deleting such an updated  question should not be a problem.

About the deleted question linked from the post:

> What's the purpose of non-void methods then? In what cases am I expected to give preference to them?

I don't think this particular question can be edited in shape suitable for SO - it asks for some sort of discussion about returning values from functions (largely matter of opinion) and unbounded list of use cases (too vague for SO).

Note that the author of the question is expected to be somewhat aware of general CS topics like object-oriented programming vs. procedural programming vs. functional programming... The question is essentially claiming that functional programming should not exist - that is a tough sell, especially for someone who look novice in the field.

Comment: I didn't claim that, I was genuinely wondering